# change page.php?id=something-new-url-5dd669f4882a6

Tags: .htaccess, seo

i want to rewrite url from page.php?id=something-new-url-5dd669f4882a6 to domain.com/something-new-url-5dd669f4882a6 
i have done some htaccess practices but it is not working. 
here are my codes.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php\?id=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

my project is in directory like ,

```
www.example.com/demo/page.php?id=something-new-url-5dd669f4882a6
```

and i want to make it seo friendly

```
domain.com/demo/something-new-url-5dd669f4882a6
```

Comment: You did not consider the `demo` folder in the pattern inside your rewriting condition.

Comment: i have changed folder, still its saying 404 not found. Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php\?id=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /demo/%1? [R=301,L]

Comment: I wrote in the pattern of the condition, not in the rule's target.

Answer (score 1):

Look this: [redirect in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Page.php:

```
<php>

    $tb=explode('=', $_GET);
    if (isset($tb[1]) && $tb[0]=='id') header('Location: domain.com/demo/' . $tb[1]);
    exit();

</php>
```